# Rails: Where do I put my API methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm very new to Rails, and I'm a little overwhelmed where I do simple things like create an API call. I've set up a route at `/reports` which has this controller:

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController

  @client = # Api-accessing gem

  @all_reports = []

  def self.request_report

    begin
      puts "Step 1:"
      step1 = @client.request_report(opts = {"max_count" => 1})
      step1_result = step1.parse
      puts "Done!"
      puts step1_result

    rescue Excon::Errors::ServiceUnavailable => e
      puts "Didn't work"
      logger.warn e.response.message
      retry
    end
  end # End request_report

  request_report

end
```

This correctly calls the external API when I first load the `/reports` route, but when I refresh the page the code *isn't* re-run.

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what controllers are used for? Am I meant to be putting this code somewhere else? Or is there a caching issue?

Answer (score 8):

The only public API of controller are the *actions* which respond to a HTTP request. In your case `get "/reports" => "reports#request_report"` is a route which corresponds to the action `request_report`.

However actions are instance methods, not class methods:

```
class ReportsController
  def request_report # self.request_report would make this a class method!
    # @todo get reports from somewhere and
    # return some sort of response.
  end

  # any method call here happens when the class is evaluated.
end
```

You are declaring the action as a class method and then calling it when the ReportsController class is evaluated. Sorry to say but just about everything about your controller is wrong.

The Rails convention would be to call the action `index`.

Controllers in Rails should only be instantiated by the router (or your test framework). So they are definatly the wrong place to put resuable  bits and bobs. If you ever see someone doing `ReportsController.new.foo` or `ReportsController.foo` - fire them on the spot.

### So where do you put external API calls?

If its a pretty trivial one-off you can place it in private method in your controller.

Some place API calls on the model layer - however that is debatable since ActiveRecord models already are supercharged to the gills with powers and responsibilities.

One solution that has worked well for me is [Service Objects](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services). They are easy to test and have a clear single responsibility.

```
class RequestReportService
  def initalize(client)
    @client = client
  end 
  def call(opts = {})
   begin
      return @client.request_report(opts.merge("max_count" => 1))
    rescue Excon::Errors::ServiceUnavailable => e
      nil
    end
  end
end

class ReportsController
  def index
    @reports = RequestReportService.new(@client).call
  end
end
```

Comment: However one word of advice is to learn how to create basic rails apps before you start dealing with external api's. Rails is extremely powerful if you understand the conventions but its an absolute mess if you just try to figure everything out as you go along.

Comment: Any more information on service objects? Do you need a separate gem for them?

Comment: @RichPeck no, you don't need a gem, you just need to append `app/services` to the rails autoload path and you are good to go. They are just plain old ruby objects that just do a single job. http://brewhouse.io/blog/2014/04/30/gourmet-service-objects.html

Comment: @RichPeck Brandon Keepers has pretty interesting talk on the subject as well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxPKljUkFQw

Answer (score 2):

To add to `@max`'s excellent answer, you need to appreciate that Rails is based on a *stateless* protocol ([`HTTP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol))...

> each request message can [only] be understood in **isolation**.

This means that if you want to create a set of controller actions, you have to appreciate that each call is going to create a new [instance](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) of your classes etc. This, coupled with the idea of a [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) set of actions, should give you a basis from which to build your functionality.

--

```
#config/routes
scope constraints: { subdomain: "api" } do
  resources :reports #-> http://api.url.com/reports
end

#app/controllers/reports_controller.rb
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :json #-> requires "responders" gem

   def index #-> instance method
      @reports = Report.all
      respond_with @reports #-> all reports
   end

   def show
      @report = Report.find params[:id]
      respond_with @report
   end
end
```

I'll leave the service object stuff as I have no experience with it.

--

If you're pulling from an external API, you have several considerations:

> 1. Calls ideally need to be [*asynchronous*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O) (unless you use multi-threading)
> 2. Calls need to be made in the *instance* method

Your current pattern calls the API on the *class*, which is why you can't refresh it:

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  @client = # Api-accessing gem
```

`@client` is only invoked (I don't know why it works, as it should be a [*class* variable](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/)) with the class.

So if you send a new `request` (which creates an *instance* of `ReportsController`), `@client` is going to be declared that one time.

To get it working correctly, `@client` needs to be defined with each *instance* method:

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @client = # Api-accessing gem
```

This way, each time you invoke `ReportsController#index`, a new API call will be made. Might seem trivial, but the data scope is massive.

---

Finally, you need to read up about [`MVC` (`Model View Controller`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller):

[image]

This will show you how `controllers` are meant to be used in Rails applications etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well I actually never seen anyone code like this in a rails controller. Rails is a mvp framework. Controller are use to negotiate between your model and the views. First of all, if you routed correctly to your controller like 

`get "/reports" => "request_report#reports"`

your controller should have a method like the following

`def request_report
  @client = Client.find(params[:id]) 
end`

And then the controller will render and display the view in your app/views/reports/request_report.html.erb with access to the @client variable you just search from your database.

I am not sure why you are calling the block request_report at the bottom of the page, it just doesn't make sense in a controller. And you certainly don't really need to write self in front of a controller method.

`def self.request_report
 your code
end`

As for where to put your api controller, usually for an api controller, we can create new folders under controllers, so the structure will be like

`app/controllers/api/v1/your_api_controller.rb`

Then in your_api_controller.rb you will need to add namespace infront of your controller like this.

`class Api::V1::ReportsController < ActionController::Base
end`

It is the same with your routes, you will add namespace in your route.rb

`namespace :api do 
  namespace :v1 do 
    get "/reports" => "request_report#reports"
  end
end`